# SQL for many to one to many table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have three tables in an Access database that I am using in java via ucanaccess.

```
Patients (PK Pt_ID)
Endoscopy (PK Endo_ID, FK Pt_ID)
Histology (PK Histol_ID, FK Pt_ID)
```

1 patient can have many endoscopies
1 patient can have many histologies
Endoscopy and histology are not related

I want to retrieve all the Endoscopies and histologies for a single patients in a single SQL query. Although I can write select statements for two tables I don't know how to do this across the three tables. Is it something like this

```
Select *.Endoscopy,*.Histology from Patients INNER JOIN Endoscopy, Histology ON Patient.Pt_Id=Endoscopy.Pt_ID, Patient.Pt_Id=Histology.Pt_ID
```

I'm sure that's a mess though...

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `Endoscopy` records or multiple `Histology` records for the same `Patient` then you will receive duplicate/repeated records in your SELECT. I do no think there is a way around that unless you use 2 SELECT statements instead of 1.

---

```
SELECT Endoscopy.*, Histology.*
FROM Patients 
INNER JOIN Endoscopy ON Patients.Pt_Id = Endoscopy.Pt_ID
INNER JOIN Histology ON Patients.Pt_Id = Histology.Pt_ID
```

- To select all records on a table in the select its table name/table alias .*
- `INNER JOIN` will only select records where there is a relationship, once one of these tables does not contain a `Pt_ID` where it is contained in any one of the other tables then no record will be displayed with that `Pt_ID`
- To add additional tables continue to add additional join statements
- You used `Patients` (with S) in one location and `Patient` (no S) in another, make sure you use the correct naming. I am guessing its `Patients` but maybe its `Patient`.

---

This statement does almost the same as the above but uses LEFT JOIN syntax so that you will always get records for both tables even if one of the two tables does not have a record for a patient.

```
SELECT Endoscopy.*, Histology.*
FROM Patients 
LEFT JOIN Endoscopy ON Patients.Pt_Id = Endoscopy.Pt_ID
LEFT JOIN Histology ON Patients.Pt_Id = Histology.Pt_ID
WHERE Histology.Histol_ID IS NOT NULL OR Endoscopy.Endo_ID IS NOT NULL
```

The added `WHERE` clause ensures that you do not get a record with all `NULL` values where there is a patient but no records in either of those tables.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of SQL DB are you using?
I believe this works on most.

```
SELECT * FROM Patients, Endoscopy, Histology 
WHERE Patient.Pt_Id=Endoscopy.Pt_ID
AND Patient.Pt_Id=Histology.Pt_ID
```

Also, I belive you have these switched around `*.Endoscopy,*.Histology` If you need to use that it should be `Endoscopy.*, Histology.*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to select both endoscopies and histologies :

```
SELECT p.Pt_ID
     , e.Endo_ID
     , h.Histol_ID
FROM Patients p
INNER JOIN Endoscopy e ON p.Pt_Id = e.Pt_ID
INNER JOIN Histology h ON p.Pt_Id = h.Pt_ID
```

But I'm not sure this is really what you want. You might need to map the tables `Patients`, `Endoscopy` and `Histology` into Java classes ? In this case, you can consider the Java Persistence API (JPA). It helps you to handle these tables in your java code. Here is a [JPA Quick Guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_quick_guide.htm).

Answer (score 0):

First idea is to use `inner join` (with correct syntax) but this is wrong. `inner join` returns patients who have **both** procedure. Pure `left join` returns additionally patients who have none. So this is the solution:

```
SELECT Patients.Pt_PK, Endoscopy.*, Histology.*
FROM Patients 
LEFT JOIN Endoscopy ON Patients.Pt_Id = Endoscopy.Pt_ID
LEFT JOIN Histology ON Patients.Pt_Id = Histology.Pt_ID
--exclude patients who don't have any
where coalesce(Endoscopy.Endo_ID, Histology.Histol_ID) is not null
```